Xylitol qualitive detection
I'm going to add xylitol into my new dental cream formula. I need cheap and easy test to verify that material I receive is indeed xylitol. Xylitol comes from ISO certified supplier so as per law there is no need to test purity, microbiology and etc. I just need to say "it is xylitol indeed" in at least loosely validatable way. Please help. My cosmetics lab is very small, say microlab, I don't have fancy equipment.
